# Paperclip Rspec tests : why missing attr_accessor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec, paperclip

I had a set of Rspec User Model tests that were passing, until I had the paperclip attribute "profile picture".

Everything is fine with paperclip, it works great, but I would like my tests also to be updated to pass. I just added this line to the @attr of the user_spec file:

```
:avatar => File.new (Rails.root + "public/images/Default_profile_picture.jpg")
```

in a before_each loop that creates a standard set of working attribute for the user model.

When I run the tests, ALL the tests give me the error message:

```
User model missing required attr_accessor for 'avatar_file_name' ...
```

Putting paperclip's fields as attr_accessor in the model makes the problem disappear in the test, but I don't think I should do this in my model (it does not work properly if I do).

Does anyone has an idea why I got these error messages when testing ? ... (I included the config line Shoulda::Matchers and the require paperclip lines in the spec/helper)

Thanks for any answer you may post !

Answer (score 8):

It was simply that I forgot to run

```
rake db:test:prepare
```

before running my tests :-/